# Secure Encryption of File on Disk

Tags: encryption, drm

I want to be able to store some data on disk after being downloaded from a server that will be fairly resistant to hacking!

What I was going to do was encrypt the data with a private key on the server and decrypt it with the public key in the client, but the data is going to be arbitrary length and will be larger then a RSA private key.

My thinking was doing it this way would mean that if a hacker managed to decompile the code and get the encryption key they would be able to decrypt it but they wouldn't actually be able to modify the data as they would still need to the private key to encrypt it again after modification for the client to load!

So i thought of a combination of asymmetric encryption with symmetric encryption to store the data. So a symmetric encryption key would be asymmetrically encoded by the server and stored along side the symmetrically encrypted data then the client would decrypt the symmetric encryption key with its public key then decrypt the data!

But then I realised a hacker would just need to decompile the code, get the public key, decrypt the symmetric decryption key, decrypt the data, modify it then re-encrypt with the symmetric decryption key and he has hacked the system.

**My question is does anyone have a suggestion in how I could go about storing this data on the client without it being hackable without knowing the private key! The data needs to be decrypt-able offline without any connection to a server required! So this rules out getting the data/keys from the server all the time!**

Comment: *'will be larger then a RSA private key'* - The solution to this is to encrypt the data with an AES key, encrypt the AES key with the RSA key and send the result along with the data.

Comment: *'decompile the code, get the public key'* So what? You cant decrypt anything with a public key - thats the private keys job

Comment: Hi Alex K, I mentioned all the points you just raised above

Comment: Operating systems provide private key storage facilities; you should state which one your using

Comment: It will be basically super multi platform, Desktops, Mobile, Consoles, Servers etc

Comment: If I can decompile your code to get the private key, then I can a) put a new private key in there so it loads the data or b) I can remove the encryption code so it loads plain data.

Comment: Well the client code will ideally hold the public key which can only be used for decryption, and the private key on the server would still be needed for encryption

Comment: Trust me when I say that if you use a private key for encryption you are already lost. Public key for encryption,  private key for decryption, never the other way around.

Comment: @owlstead care to explain why?

Comment: Well, encryption is for achieving confidentiality. When you can decrypt with a public key that's already out of yhe window. If you want integrity you need signature generation and a different padding method.

Comment: Yeah okay a client being able to decrypt the data is fine with me, and the average user will only be able to do that through the app, with hackers being able to maybe get hold of that key and decrypt it that way! What I'm trying to ensure is that a user can't modify the data in anyway and have the app load it after they have done so! So what I'm thinking is a send an asymmetrically encrypted checksum over with the file and as long as they can't modify the checksum (the can decrypt it to the hearts content), because they would need the private key to do so, this might work?

Comment: Possibly. Simply using RSA to sign the data would be standard and would accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no secure way to store data on the client. When data is on the client, a dedicated mind has all the tools and all the time in the universe to crack the best encryption that you can come up with.

There are two solutions:

1. Trust your client.
2. Stream the data.

Comments: If your client is also your enemy, then there is no way you can make business with them. The movie industry learned this, the music industry learned this, the book industry is learning it and the games industry is following. These people spent billions in clever DRM technologies and they all failed.

You want the customer's money? Then treat them accordingly.

Streaming is about the only workaround that balances trust and security. Streaming means that at any time, only a small fraction of the data is on the client at any time and combining the fragments into a whole data set is complex.

Comment: But a custom streaming client could save the streamed data rather than discard it after viewing. In other words, streaming is simply another DRM scheme.